# Adding incrementTo(num, time, pace) to counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, counter, auto-increment

I'm using this counter (http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter-revisited/#options) and I'm trying to make the counter stop at **'150'**.

The website above says that the function I need to use is called: **myCounter.incrementTo(150, 10, 400);** This will increment to 150 as well, but the increment process will take 10 seconds to complete. The counter will determine the optimal values to use. In the example I've set a desired pace of 400, which the counter will try and stay as close to as possible when finding the optimal values. This method is not chainable.

The counter does not seem to recognize this function, could someone tell me what I am missing here?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>CSS Flip-Counter Revisited</title>

  <!-- Counter script -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flipcounter.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.21954.js"></script>
  <!-- Counter styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

</head>

<body>
<h1>COUNTER</h1>

  <div class="counter-wrapper">
    <ul class="flip-counter huge" id="myCounter"></ul>
  </div>


<script>

    var myCounter = new flipCounter("myCounter", {inc: 25, pace: 400});

    myCounter.setAuto(true);
    myCounter.incrementTo(150, 10, 400);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
    /**
 * CSS Flip Counter
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Chris Nanney
 *
 * http://cnanney.com/journal/code/css-flip-counter-revisited/
 *
 * Licensed under MIT
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

var flipCounter = function(d, options){

  // Default values
  var defaults = {
    value: 0,
    inc: 1,
    pace: 1000,
    auto: true
  };

  var counter = options || {};
  var doc = window.document;

  for (var opt in defaults){
    counter[opt] = counter.hasOwnProperty(opt) ? counter[opt] : defaults[opt];
  }

  var digitsOld = [], digitsNew = [], digitsAnimate = [], x, y, nextCount = null;

  var div = d;
  if (typeof d === 'string'){
    div = doc.getElementById(d);
  }

  /**
   * Sets the value of the counter and animates the digits to new value.
   *
   * Example: myCounter.setValue(500); would set the value of the counter to 500,
   * no matter what value it was previously.
   *
   * @param {int} n
   *   New counter value
   */
  this.setValue = function(n){
    if (_isNumber(n)){
      x = counter.value;
      y = counter.value = n;
      _digitCheck(x, y);
    }
    return this;
  };

  /**
   * Sets the increment for the counter. Does NOT animate digits.
   */
  this.setIncrement = function(n){
    counter.inc = _isNumber(n) ? n : defaults.inc;
    return this;
  };

  /**
   * Sets the pace of the counter. Only affects counter when auto == true.
   *
   * @param {int} n
   *   New pace for counter in milliseconds
   */
  this.setPace = function(n){
    counter.pace = _isNumber(n) ? n : defaults.pace;
    return this;
  };

  /**
   * Sets counter to auto-increment (true) or not (false).
   *
   * @param {boolean} a
   *   Should counter auto-increment, true or false
   */
  this.setAuto = function(a){
    var sa = typeof a !== "boolean" ? true : a;
    if (counter.auto){
      if (!sa){
        if (nextCount) _clearNext();
        counter.auto = false;
      }
    }
    else{
      if (sa){
        if (nextCount) _clearNext();
        counter.auto = true;
        _doCount();
      }
    }
    return this;
  };

  /**
   * Increments counter by one animation based on set 'inc' value.
   */
  this.step = function(){
    if (!counter.auto) _doCount();
    return this;
  };

  /**
   * Adds a number to the counter value, not affecting the 'inc' or 'pace' of the counter.
   *
   * @param {int} n
   *   Number to add to counter value
   */
  this.add = function(n){
    if (_isNumber(n)){
      x = counter.value;
      counter.value += n;
      y = counter.value;
      _digitCheck(x, y);
    }
    return this;
  };

  /**
   * Subtracts a number from the counter value, not affecting the 'inc' or 'pace' of the counter.
   *
   * @param {int} n
   *   Number to subtract from counter value
   */
  this.subtract = function(n){
    if (_isNumber(n)){
      x = counter.value;
      counter.value -= n;
      if (counter.value >= 0){
        y = counter.value;
      }
      else{
        y = "0";
        counter.value = 0;
      }
      _digitCheck(x, y);
    }
    return this;
  };

  /**
   * Gets current value of counter.
   */
  this.getValue = function(){
    return counter.value;
  }

  /**
   * Stops all running increments.
   */
  this.stop = function(){
    if (nextCount) _clearNext();
    return this;
  }

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  function _doCount(first){
    var first_run = typeof first === "undefined" ? false : first;
    x = counter.value;
    if (!first_run) counter.value += counter.inc;
    y = counter.value;
    _digitCheck(x, y);
    // Do first animation
    if (counter.auto === true) nextCount = setTimeout(_doCount, counter.pace);
  }

  function _digitCheck(x, y){
    digitsOld = _toArray(x);
    digitsNew = _toArray(y);
    var ylen = digitsNew.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < ylen; i++){
      digitsAnimate[i] = digitsNew[i] != digitsOld[i];
    }
    _drawCounter();
  }

  // Creates array of digits for easier manipulation
  function _toArray(input){
    return input.toString().split('').reverse();
  }

  // Sets the correct digits on load
  function _drawCounter(){
    var bit = 1, html = '', dNew, dOld;
    for (var i = 0, count = digitsNew.length; i < count; i++){
      dNew = _isNumber(digitsNew[i]) ? digitsNew[i] : '';
      dOld = _isNumber(digitsOld[i]) ? digitsOld[i] : '';
      html += '<li class="digit" id="'+d+'-digit-a'+i+'">'+
        '<div class="line"></div>'+
        '<span class="front">'+dNew+'</span>'+
        '<span class="back">'+dOld+'</span>'+
        '<div class="hinge">'+
        '<span class="front">'+dOld+'</span>'+
        '<span class="back">'+dNew+'</span>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</li>';
      if (bit !== count && bit % 3 === 0){
        html += '<li class="digit-delimiter">,</li>';
      }
      bit++;
    }

    div.innerHTML = html;

    var alen = digitsAnimate.length;

    // Need a slight delay before adding the 'animate' class or else animation won't fire on FF
    setTimeout(function(){
      for (var i = 0; i < alen; i++){
        if (digitsAnimate[i]){
          var a = doc.getElementById(d+'-digit-a'+i);
          a.className = a.className+' animate';
        }
      }
    }, 20)

  }

  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844
  function _isNumber(n){
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
  }

  function _clearNext(){
    clearTimeout(nextCount);
    nextCount = null;
  }

  // Start it up
  _doCount(true);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to run this script on dom ready

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', runCounter, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onload', runCounter);
}
```

do like this :

```
<script>
    var runCounter = function(){
        var myCounter = new flipCounter("myCounter", {inc: 25, pace: 400});

        myCounter.setAuto(true);
        myCounter.incrementTo(150, 10, 400);
    };


    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', runCounter, false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent('onload', runCounter);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Cezary, were exactly do I need to place this?

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work, the counter just keep on going.

Comment: Hmm, I miss understood your question, 
so script works but doesn't stop on limit value ? yes ?

I just checked it, 
and your code is working

Comment: Yes it does not stop at limit value, in this example that is 150.

Comment: thats weird on my local it's working fine,
but on fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/DH6Kp/8/) is broken,
sorry don't know why

Comment: There is a demo website: http://demo.cnanney.com/apple-counter-revisited/ where they display an function called "Increment To:". When you click on this button, the counter stop at '12.345' but there is a click needed. There should be a way to use this function without clicking on a button right?

Comment: Cezary I managed to fix you code! Try removing:     myCounter.setAuto(true);

Comment: Final question, can you send me a working .zip of the counter? I can not get it from JSFiddle right?

Comment: you can get it from JSFiddle,
the same code works for me on local